# 64 bit helper function Handle64toHandle()

Tags: c, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

Am trying to resolve the logical error of below code using MSVC 64 bit compiler.

This code was running fine in 32 machines previously.

```
return ((ULONG) DupThreadHandle);
```

In 64 bit world, I learnt that any thread handle is 64 bit(actually 6byte), so this code is obviously wrong, because destination type is ULONG which is 32 bit.

But msdn recommends to use helper function which I mentioned in title for 64 bit porting for C code by including basetsd.h

But my question is, how such helper functions conceptually change 6 byte address to 4 byte address? Because already thread is placed at some 6 byte address. How meaningful is this 4 byte address?
I do not want to change destination type. because problem will be recursive warnings.

Comment: on the same lines, i can generalise the question, how ptr64toptr()  and  ptrtouint() work in 64 bit world? Because if this helper functions provide 32 bit value, i need to understand how this 32 bit value refer the 64 bit value, if i try derefencing such 32 bit pointers?   Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Microsoft [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810720),...

> To facilitate the porting, a decision has been made that these system
>   handles should stay as 32b values, sign extended to 64b on the 64b
>   platform. That is, the individual handle types are still based on the
>   HANDLE type, which maps to void *, and so the size of the handle is
>   the size of the pointer, i.e. 4 bytes on 32b and 8 bytes on 64b.
>   However, the actual value of the handle on the 64b platform, (i.e. the
>   meaningful bits), fits within the lower 32b, while the upper bits just
>   carry the sign.

See also, [this](http://www.viva64.com/en/d/0157/).

The effect of the Handle64toHandle() function can be duplicated yourself by simply casting between 64-bit and 32-bit types, but...  this is the BIG BUT.....  you have to cast using `signed` types.  Your cast using an `unsigned` type twarts Microsoft's treatment of addresses as signed quantities, as explained above.  Change your casting to use `signed` types and you should be fine.  But you need to make sure you store any such addresses in `signed` 32-bit types, so that they are properly converted back to the proper 64-bit type later without losing the all-ones state of the top bits.  If you can't do that for legacy reasons (i.e. storing them in a 32-bit unsigned integer that's part of legacy code that you can't change), then be sure to cast those unsigned values back to signed values when making the conversion back to 64-bits.

Comment: am bit confused on point, that lower 4 bytes has meaningful bits as part of address, please correct me, i learnt that in 64 bit machines, 6 byte address is used to refer a memory, so what about remaining 2 bytes after using helper function?

Comment: @user2025667 - Not sure what OS / system your class was for, but treating only 6 bytes of an 8-byte 64-bit pointer as significant would be a system-dependent issue.  Some 64-bit systems may use all 8 bytes.  In any case, I believe that Windows systems consider pointers to be "signed", with user-related stuff in the lower half of the address space ("positive" addresses) and OS-related stuff in the upper half ("negative" addresses).  This situation lends itself easily to extension from a 32-bit address space to a 64-bit address space: Consider how a "negative" 32-bit address is represented:...

Comment: ...Its high bit is by definition set (i.e. 1).  Now represent that same signed value in 64 bits:  The lower 4 bytes are exactly the same, we just add 4 all-ones bytes to the top, sign-extending the 32-bit value to 64 bits.  E.g. 32-bit 0x80123456 is the exact same signed integral value as 64-bit 0xffffffff80123456.  If a compiler, in an appropriate conversion function, issues the correct instructions for handling those numbers, conversion between 32-bit and 64-bit pointers is trivial.  But this trivial conversion only works for pointers in the bottom 2GB and top 2GB of an address space....

Comment: ...thus, for simplicity, Microsoft made the guarantee that handles will only be assigned pointer values (addresses) that can validly be converted this way.

Comment: hello phonetagger      ##are you saying that, in 64 bit world, windows api like malloc(),createwindproc(),_beginthread() etc... Will have meaningful bits in only lower 4 bytes and higher 4 bytes will only have either 0's or f's which are not part of the address? Is that what you are saying?   If yes, then i can ignore this warning, because anyways i need lower 4 bytes only in such scenario?  But if only lower 4 bytes only have meaningful bits, then my app will only have 2^31 address space range to use, not more that, which is ame as 32 bit, what is the advantage of 64 bit binary ?

Comment: Hello I have written the following code to check the same point and it is not working only difference id am using ptrtolong() instead of Handle64toHandle() and another point is,  i set HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\AllocationPreference to DWORD: 0x100000 and restart so that i can get only 8 byte addresses

Comment: #include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <BaseTsd.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
              int * ptr = NULL;
     long l;
              int i=10;
     ptr = &i;
     printf("Pointer = %p \n", ptr);
     printf("Data = %d \n", *(ptr));
     l = PtrToLong(ptr);
              printf("Converted Pointer = %l \n", l);
                   


   _getch();
    return 0;

}

Comment: output is Pointer = 000000000019FD94
Data = 10
Converted Pointer =

Comment: Hello moderator,              if this is an extended discussion, please let me know, how do you recommend me to proceed because my discussion is not complete yet.

Comment: after reading msdn link thoroughly i understood you point.please ignore past 4 updates.   thx

Comment: @user2025667 - Sorry I missed your questions last night.  The "extra 4 bytes" (high 4 bytes) ARE part of the address... and as long as everybody treats addresses as `signed` entities, and as long as the OS promises to only give out handles that are in the top 2G or bottom 2G of the address space, the high 4 bytes "magically" reappear when casting back from 32-bits to 64-bits.  (Well, it's not magic, it's just the nature of sign extending due to casting signed values.)  BTW, you can go back & delete any comments you wish you never posted.  If you have any further questions, let me know.